# how to get unique row numbers in sql

Tags: sql, datetime, where-clause, greatest-n-per-group

How to get only the first row from the result of the below query. I need the latest record for each date so I did the partition by created_date. But in some places, I am getting the same row number and not able to get the expected output. Please find the below query, current output, and expected output.

What changes do in need to make in order to get the expected output? Thank you.

```
WITH ctetable
AS (
    SELECT created_date BPMDate
        ,tenor
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY created_date ORDER BY created_date DESC
            ) rw
    FROM table1 a
    INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.case_id = b.case_id
        AND a.eligible_transaction = 'true'
        AND to_date(a.created_date) >= '2020-10-01'
        AND to_date(a.created_date) <= '2020-10-05'
        AND case_status = 'Completed'
    )
SELECT BPMDate
    ,Tenor
    ,rw
FROM ctetable
```

Current output:

```
date                tenor   rw
2020-10-05 13:24:15.0   1W      1
2020-10-05 12:15:43.0   1Y      1
2020-10-05 12:15:43.0   1Y      2
2020-10-01 13:30:59.0   1W      1
2020-10-01 13:30:59.0   1W      2
```

Expected output:

```
 date               tenor   rw
2020-10-05 13:24:15.0   1W      1
2020-10-01 13:30:59.0   1W      1
```

Regards,
Viresh

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

That would be:

```
with ctetable as  (  
    select created_date, bpmdate, tenor, 
        row_number() over (partition by date(created_date) order by created_date desc ) rn
    from table1 a  
    inner join table2 b
        on  a.case_id = b.case_id 
        and a.eligible_transaction = 'true' 
        and to_date(a.created_date) >=  '2020-10-01' 
        and to_date(a.created_date) <=  '2020-10-05' 
        and case_status='completed'
    ) 
select bpmdate,tenor,rw
from ctetable
where rn = 1
```

Changes to your original code:

- you need to remove the time portion of the date in the `partition by` clause of the window function; you didn't tell which database you are using: I  used `date()`, but the function might be different in your database (`trunc()` in Oracle, `date_trunc()` in Postgres, and so on)
- the outer query needs to filter on the row number that is equal to `1`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the first row per day:

```
select BPMDate, Tenor, rw
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by trunc(bpmdate) order by bpmdate) as seqnum
      from ctetable
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  I don't know if your database supports `trunc()`, but that is simply some method for extracting the date from the column.